# supercsv writing form database

Tags: csv, supercsv

I am getting some issue with SuperCSV writing. I have created a web application module to export CSV file from DB.so the problem is how i can work with  CustomerBean i find this code but the customer here is static:

```
final CustomerBean john = new CustomerBean("1", "John", "Dunbar",
                new GregorianCalendar(1945, Calendar.JUNE, 13).getTime(),
                "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway\nMountain View, CA 94043\nUnited States", null, null,
                "\"May the Force be with you.\" - Star Wars", "jdunbar@gmail.com", 0L);
```

I get this result:
unable to find getter for filed First Name in class jaca.util.HashMap -check that the corresponding nameMapping element matches the filed name in the bean

Comment: Can you post a code example showing what you're actually trying to do? It sounds like you're trying to use CsvBeanWriter with a HashMap - if so you should use CsvMapWriter instead.

Comment: As Hound Dog hinted to, try the ICsvMapWriter mapWriter = new CsvMapWriter(...) instead of the CsvBeanWriter.